# Why dosen't stub S3 method in typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, sinon

I try to write unit test with S3, but it was failed with error.

I typed typescript.

method to test

```js
export const getUrlFromS3 = async (fileName: string): Promise<string> => {
  const s3: S3 = new S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  });
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `${fileName}.pdf`,
    Expires: 60 * 5
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", params, (err: Error, url: string) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(url);
    });
  });
};
```

and my test file

```
import * as manageS3 from "./manageS3";
import * as Aws from "aws-sdk";
import * as Sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("manageS3", () => {
  let sandbox: Sinon.SinonSandbox;
  beforeEach(() => (sandbox = Sinon.createSandbox()));
  afterEach(() => sandbox.reset());

  it("getUrlFromS3 test", async () => {
    sandbox
      .stub(Aws.S3.prototype, "getSignedUrl")
      .callsFake((operation, params, callback) => {
        return callback(undefined, "");
      });
    const url = await manageS3.getUrlFromS3("");
    console.log(url);
  });
});
```

and it is error message
`Argument of type '(operation: any, params: any, callback: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(operation: string, params: any) => string'.ts(2345)`

S3 has two of methods that are

```
getSignedUrl(operation: string, params: any, callback: (err: Error, url: string) => void): void;
getSignedUrl(operation: string, params: any): string;
```

Why can't the first method stub?